# Save Bitmap From ZipinputStream Directly to File

Tags: android, android-image

I have a zip file which I'm listing and sorting each file inside by iterating through the stream using `zis.getNextEntry()`.

Works fine for getting `String` objects from the ZipEntry, what I need is to save a copy to a directory in my application.

The directory part I'm fine with I just need to know how to save each bitmap straight away, without necessarily decoding it and creating a Bitmap object in memory.

This is my code to get each of the text file's contents.

```
if (decodeFile) { // WE ARE LOOKING AT A FILE WE CAN DECODE
    while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
        String string = new String(buffer, 0, read);
        s.append(string);
    }
    stringArray.add(s.toString());
} else { // WE ARE LOOKING AT AN IMAGE/DIRECTORY

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (decodeFile) { // WE ARE LOOKING AT A FILE WE CAN DECODE
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("path/name.ext");
        while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            String string = new String(buffer, 0, read);
            fw.write(string);
        }
        fw.close();
    } else { // WE ARE LOOKING AT AN IMAGE/DIRECTORY

    }
```

Maybe like so?

Comment: This is a good solution for copying the text file but how do I implement it to copy an image?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply create an OutputStream and instead of reading values to String write them directly to the OutputStream.

It should be something like this:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("foo.zip");
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("...");

in = zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry("yourbitmap.jpg"));

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    out.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: I don't have the ZipFile due to it being opened from an email. I also read to a string if its a certain file because I am not saving those. That bit is fine its just the copying of images